# need to add basic auth for uri backend but need to exlude some of the uri

Tags: .htaccess

I need to add basic auth for uri backend but need to exlude some of the uri, i have try to add SetEnvIf

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(login|admin)" PROTECTED
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/api/*" !PROTECTED
```

The idea is protect uri that containt `login` or `admin` but allow `admin/api/*`

but it's doesn't work, can you guys give me some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is problematic here:

```
`^/api/*`
```

Will match `/api` at the start and `*` is useless after `/`.

You can do this in single `SetEnvIf` rule by using negative lookahead:

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(login|admin(?!/api/))" PROTECTED
```

`(?!/api/)` means skip `/admin/api/` from this rule

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and back with the result later, I'm not on my pc yet, thanks btw.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked like a charm, I'm just modify to my need